# Geocoder undefined variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

I am trying to run the geocoder gem on rails.  When I try to get the distance between two locations, I get an error saying I have an undefined local variable or method. Does anyone know why this is happening? I tried calling it it up with a smallcase r and uppercase, but no dice.  Any help is appreciated.  [Image of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g5Ne.png)

Comment: Where do you define the `restaurant_1` variable? Also, in the feature, please copy paste the error instead of using the screenshot.

Comment: If you want to get first Restaurant, use Restaurant.find(1)

Answer (score 0):

from what I can see in your image, you didn't define restaurant_1 or restaurant_3
you can do this:

```
@restaurants = Restaurant.first(3)
@restaurants[0].distance_to(@restaurants[2])
```

I suggest you take a look at this:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#first